# Exporting a Variable Using Grunt Express in Node/Express

Tags: node.js, express, gruntjs, grunt-express

Under this example that I've been using to create my server:

https://github.com/blai/grunt-express#server

grunt-express is triggered through the 'module.exports = app' line.

However, in the same server file, I want to export a variable. I do via the following:

```
exports.hello = 'hello';
```

Though when trying to access that variable in another file in the backend, it doesn't work. I realize that this variable is being over-written by the last line 'module.exports = app', so how can I make it such that grunt-express works when the server is started, while allowing a variable to be exported to other files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just move `module.exports.hello = 'hello';` below `module.exports`

Like so

```
module.exports = {some stuff}
module.exports.hello = "hello"
```